# add smooth transition down on bootstrap dropdown

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap 3 on angularjs. Not sure what I'm missing. When I click it, it doesn't slide down/up smoothly but rather gets displayed quickly. I'm trying to achieve an effect similar to the accordion.

```
<li class="dropdown" id="printerAnalyticsMenu">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
        <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>
        <span class="hidden-xs">Printer Analytics</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="ajax-link" ui-sref="main.odometer">Odometers</a></li>
        <li><a class="ajax-link" href="#">Real Time Print Job</a></li>
        <li><a class="ajax-link" href="#">Battery</a></li>
        <li><a class="ajax-link" href="#">Printhead</a></li>
    </ul>
```

and the css

```
li#printerAnalyticsMenu > ul > li {
    /* this will apply to inner UL, adapt to your desired selector */
    -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been awhile since I have used drop-down menus myself. However try this instead:

```
li#printerAnalyticsMenu:hover ul {
    -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

**Disclaimer:** I am not familiar with this function that you are using, but this is how I would normally display a drop-down menu.

Comment: it didn't work. I was expecting that bootstrap will add a class after clicking it

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are using a jQuery plugin for this component. It would be helpful if you could include the jQuery line(s) that call the code to action.